# support old clients withopenvpn on Debian bullseye

Tags: debian, openvpn

I'm trying to replace an openvpn server running Debian stretch and openvpn 2.4.0 with one running Debian bullseye and openvpn 2.5.7, unfortunately older clients running openvpn 2.3 on an old operating system are failing to connect to the new server. I can't easily upgrade these clients right now. the client says (censored).

```
Socket Buffers: R=[163840->131072] S=[163840->131072]
UDPv4 link local: [undef]
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194
TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]xx.xx.xx.xx:1194, sid=xxxxxx xxxxxx
```

It then hangs for a while and then reports.

```
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS handshake failed
```

I've googled around a bit but struggled to find a solution, I found an answer about data channel ciphers, but things don't even seem to be getting as far as establishing the data channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are two issues that needed to be solved to get a successful connection.

The first was that the old clients only support tls 1.0, but bullseye's openvpn denies this by default (I believe the default for this relates to the configuration of the openssl library). tls 1.0 support can be re-enabled by putting `tls-version-min 1.0` in the server configuration.

The second, as described at https://blog.zs64.net/2021/01/enabling-backwards-compatibility-in-openvpn/ is the data channel cipher, openvpn no longer supports a fallback cipher for pre 2.4 openvpn clients by default. I found a greater fix was needed than specified there though. As well as setting `data-cipher-fallback` I also had to set `data-ciphers`

The final set of extra server-side settings were.

```
data-ciphers AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:AES-256-CBC
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-CBC
tls-version-min 1.0
```

While on the client I set.

```
cipher AES-256-CBC
```